# How to trace QuickSort() calls for length 3 array

Tags: recursion, computer-science, quicksort, callstack

For the CLRS algorithm for QuickSort,

I am having trouble with following all the calls for the input A = [2,1,3].

```
QuickSort(A,p,r)
  if p < r
   q = Partition(A,p,r)
   QuickSort(A,p,q-1)
   QuickSort(A,q+1,r)
```

```
Partition(A,p,r)
  x = A[r]
  i = p - 1
  for j = p to r - 1
      if A[j] <= x
        i = i + 1
        swap (A[i], A[j])
  swap(A[i+1], A[r])
  return i+1
```

Here are my function calls for array A:

1. QuickSort(A,1,3)
2. Partition(A,1,3)
3. QuickSort(A,1,2)
4. Partition(A,1,2)
5. QuickSort(A,1,0)
6. QuickSort(A,2,3)
7. Partition(A,2,3)
8. QuickSort(A,1,2)

Why does it loop from 8 on?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming indexes start at 1 and not 0, I get:

```
quicksort A 1 3
partition A 1 3
quicksort A 1 2
partition A 1 2
quicksort A 1 0
quicksort A 2 2
quicksort A 4 3
```

If indexes starts at 0, then the initial call should be QuickSort(A, 0, 2)